# Centering ul content in a div

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm a visual designer, and new to CSS. I have hit a road block and am hoping you can help me sort it out!

I have some text and images in a ul which I want centered in a div no matter how the browser is resized. I am adding this code to an adaptive wordpress theme.

```css
.clinCon {
  height: 460px;
  background: rgb(249, 255, 254); /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(249, 255, 254, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 253, 253, 1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(249, 255, 254, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 253, 253, 1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(249, 255, 254, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 253, 253, 1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+,  Safari7+ */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f9fffe', endColorstr='#fdfdfd', GradientType=1); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient     */
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
.clinCon > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 33px 0px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  color: #566471;
}
.clinCon img {
  padding: 11px 20px 0 0;
  color: #566471!important;
  width: 70px;
}
.clinCon p {
  font-size: 13px;
  position: relative;
  top: -23px;
  left: 70px;
}
```

```html
<section class="shadow">
  <div class="clinical">CLINICAL</div>
  <div class="clinCon">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="http://thrpdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/ABIT-ICON.png" class="p-icon">1-on-1 Therapy</li>
      <p class="explain">Address root causes of addiction</p>
      <li>
        <img src="http://thrpdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/ABIT-ICON.png" class="p-icon">Addiction Education</li>
      <p class="explain">Understand Addiction's inner workings</p>
      <li>
        <img src="http://thrpdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/ABIT-ICON.png" class="p-icon">Literary Therapy</li>
      <p class="explain">Identify, process and resolve trauma</p>
      <li>
        <img src="http://thrpdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/ABIT-ICON.png" class="p-icon">Process Group</li>
      <p class="explain">Connect with a group of your peers</p>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!!

Comment: As of now, your question is unclear. Please provide a [mcve] so it can be inspected. Also please specify exactly in what element you want the images centered, how they should be positioned relative to one another and if you want horizontal or vertical alignment, or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed your **HTML** and **CSS** to meet your requirement....

```css
.clinCon{
height:auto;
background: rgb(249,255,254); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(249,255,254,1) 0%,      rgba(253,253,253,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(249,255,254,1)  0%,rgba(253,253,253,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(249,255,254,1) 0%,rgba(253,253,253,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+,  Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f9fffe',   endColorstr='#fdfdfd',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient     */
border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
}

.clinCon > ul{
list-style-type: none;
position: relative;
font-size: 22px;
letter-spacing: 0.05em;
color: #566471;
}
.clinCon > ul > li {
    height: 70px;
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 0px;
}
.clinCon img{
color: #566471!important;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.clinCon span{
display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.clinCon p{
font-size: 13px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 !important;
    margin-left: -35px;
}
```

```html
<section class="shadow">
<div class="clinical">CLINICAL</div>
<div class="clinCon">
 <ul>
  <li><img src="http://thrpdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/ABIT-ICON.png" class="p-icon"><span>1-on-1 Therapy</span><p class="explain">Address root causes of addiction</p></li>
  <li><img src="http://thrpdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/ABIT-ICON.png" class="p-icon"><span>Addiction Education</span><p class="explain">Understand Addiction's inner workings</p></li>
  <li><img src="http://thrpdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/ABIT-ICON.png" class="p-icon"><span>Literary Therapy</span><p class="explain">Identify, process and resolve trauma</p></li>
  <li><img src="http://thrpdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/ABIT-ICON.png" class="p-icon"><span>Process Group</span><p class="explain">Connect with a group of your peers</p></li>
 </ul>
</div>
</section>
```

Check This out and let me know if it meets your requirement...

Comment: Not only you posted an answer with a solution that has already been proposed, but you also misspelled the property value, making sure it won't work. It is recommended you test any code before posting it.

Answer (score 1):

Not Sure If you want to achieve this,

```css
.clinCon {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgb(249, 255, 254);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(249, 255, 254, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 253, 253, 1) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(249, 255, 254, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 253, 253, 1) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(249, 255, 254, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 253, 253, 1) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+,  Safari7+ */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f9fffe', endColorstr='#fdfdfd', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient     */
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
.clinCon > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 33px 0px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  color: #566471;
}
.clinCon img {
  padding: 11px 20px 0 0;
  color: #566471!important;
  width: 70px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2em;
}
.clinCon p {
  font-size: 13px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 3em;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<section class="shadow">
  <div class="clinical">CLINICAL</div>
  <div class="clinCon">

    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="http://thrpdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/ABIT-ICON.png" class="p-icon">

        <p class="explain">Process Group
          <br>Connect with a group of your peers</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That helps a lot. However, that stacks the image above the text and explanation. What I am trying to do is keep the image to the left with the title and explanation to the right. Does this make sense? The link below should illustrate it - the image is the circle and the text and explanation are the lines. http://www.freepik.com/free-icon/list-in-bullet-form_735762.htm Again, thanks so much!!